# output varchar with html tags from sql - output is encoded and should not be

Tags: php, mysql, string, varchar

Saving input from a form field into sql database varchar(255)... The input would be something like :

```
<a href="test.com">Author Name</a>
```

Bottom line is it will more than likely have html tags in it most of the time.  When I retrieve and output from the database I get something like :

```
&lt;a href=&quot;test.com&quot;&gt;Author Name&lt;/a&gt;
```

As this should be echo'ed as html it does not show properly on the page.  Maybe I am just tired, but I cannot figure out how to output this as non-encoded so it is properly read by the browser.

Comment: That depends on how are you inserting them into database...but anyway,  `html_entity_decode` or `htmlspecialchars_decode` should be able to convert them back.

Comment: html_entity_decode did the trick...I knew there was something like that and couldn't remember anything... time for some sleep!  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php
    echo htmlspecialchars_decode("&lt;a href=&quot;test.com&quot;&gt;Author Name&lt;/a&gt;");
?>
```

Why do you encode the html tags before inserting into the database?

Answer (score 0):

```
#Connect to the DB
$db = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');

#Select the DB name
mysql_select_db('test');

#html tag contain in a string='$str'
$str='<a href="test'.'.com"'.'>Author Name</a>';

###insert query section ###

#Ask for UTF-8 encoding
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

#Set the Query
$sql = "INSERT INTO `test`.`code` (`name`) VALUES ('$str');";//Save it in a text row, that's it...

#Run the query
mysql_query($sql);

###fetching result###

#fetching required info from mysql
$sqlQuery1 = "SELECT * FROM `code` WHERE `name` LIKE '$str'";

$result1 = mysql_query($sqlQuery1);  //order executes                                                                                  
$row1 = mysql_fetch_array($result1);
if( $row1){    
echo $row1['name'] ;
}

#HOPE THIS HELP YOU ALOT
```